# TypeError: edges() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I ran a sparsification algorithm on a graph and am trying to import the graph into CSV file as edgelist. When I use the .write_edlist() method in python networkx, I get the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/sindhuja/sparsegraph/sparsify.py", line 41, in <module>
>     nx.write_edgelist(S, 'sparsified_graph.csv')   File "<decorator-gen-512>", line 2, in write_edgelist   File
> "/Users/sindhuja/PycharmProjects/kit.py/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py",
> line 227, in _open_file
>     result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/sindhuja/PycharmProjects/kit.py/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/edgelist.py",
> line 177, in write_edgelist
>     for line in generate_edgelist(G, delimiter, data):   File "/Users/sindhuja/PycharmProjects/kit.py/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/edgelist.py",
> line 114, in generate_edgelist
>     for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True): TypeError: edges() takes no keyword arguments
```

This is the code snippet I am running:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Dict, Any
import pandas as pd
from IPython.utils import data
from networkit import *
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from networkit.graphio import GraphConverter
from numpy import genfromtxt
import metis as mt
from networkx.utils import make_str
from _NetworKit import Graph

df1 = pd.read_csv ( 'person_knows_person_0_0.csv', sep='|', index_col=False )
df2 = pd.DataFrame ( df1 )
src_list = df2[':START_ID(Person)'].values.tolist ()
tgt_list = df2[':END_ID(Person)'].values.tolist ()

print ( src_list[1] )
print ( tgt_list[1] )
f = open ( 'sample_ex.csv', 'w' )
for (src, tgt) in zip ( src_list, tgt_list ):
    f.write ( str ( src ) + ',' + str ( tgt ) + '\n' )
f.close ()
reader = graphio.EdgeListReader ( ',', 1, continuous=False )
G = reader.read ( 'sample_ex.csv' )
print ( G )
graphio.writeGraph ( G, 'newgraph.graph', Format.METIS )
metisgraph = graphio.readGraph ( "newgraph.graph", Format.METIS )
print ( metisgraph )
G.indexEdges ()
print ( "Original size: ", G.size () )

sparsificationAlgorithm = sparsification.LocalDegreeSparsifier ()
S = sparsificationAlgorithm.getSparsifiedGraph ( G, 0.5 )
print ( "Sparsified size: ", S.size () )


nx.write_edgelist(S, 'sparsified_graph.edgelist', ',')
```

I am new to networkx and it could be that I am not passing arguments to write_edgelist() method properly. Could some help me?

Comment: Q1: What version of networkx are you using?

Comment: Q2: Can you provide code that I can copy and paste and have it run?  

So import all the packages you need, don't rely on reading in stuff from files?

Comment: I am using networkx 2.1 version. I dint quite get second part of your second question. But editing the question to include all the imports.

Comment: You should show how `S` looks like since it may be there the error.

Comment: Take a look at [mcve].  I don't have sample_ex.csv.  So if I copy and paste this, I'll get an error.  Please reduce the example to something that will run if I copy and paste it.

Comment: what version of networkx are you using?